# Xamarin ios app crashes on launch due to missing library MapboxCore.dysl

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I ended up creating a "slim" binding following the guide from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough

I've loaded all the Mapbox frameworks into the swift project and I can use the library I built in swift inside another swift application with no issue.  When I move the library into my Xamarin application though, I get the following error at runtime and the app immediately crashes:

dyld[4157]: Library not loaded: @rpath/MapboxCoreMaps.framework/MapboxCoreMaps
iOS.app/Frameworks/MapboxCoreMaps.framework/MapboxCoreMaps' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

I've looked at the framework package and it appears the same as all the other packages.  I tried setting Xcode to launch with Rosetta but that didn't seem to make any difference.  I've tried older versions of Mapbox and still get the error.  Anyone encounter this in a 3rd party native library before?

Answer (score 0):

For those who run into this after me.  Steps that ended up fixing this:

1. Turned off smart linking for 3rd party native packages
2. Moved the third party native packages from the binding library to the main project
3. Set frameworks to static instead of framework